# mongoDB $in check if array is empty?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This function works as intended.

```js
static getUsersWithTasks = (ids) => {
  const db = getDb();
  return db
    .collection(process.env.USERSCOLLECTION)
    .aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: { $in: ids } } },
      {
        $project: {
          password: 0,
          tokens: 0,
          spaces: 0,
          incomingSpaceInvites: 0,
          incomingFriendRequest: 0,
          friends: 0
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "challenges",
          let: { tasks: "$tasks" },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$tasks"] }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "populatedTasks"
        }
      }
    ])
    .toArray();
};
```

However, some users only have an empty `tasks` array, because they have yet to create a task.

If a user therefore has an empty `tasks` array, then I get a mongodb error, because $in requires an array as second argument.

If all users have a value in the `tasks` array, then everything works fine.

My question is:

Is there a way to skip the lookup phase, if that users `tasks` array is empty?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In the `$project` stage you can substitute the `tasks` field value with an array of a dummy value or an array with zero elements (whenever the field is empty). What do you mean by: _empty tasks array_?

Answer (score 0):

You got two options:

1. Use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to split your aggregation into 2 (one for users with tasks and one for users without), however this creates a "messy" pipeline and I'm not sure its going to be more efficient then using option 2 (if you try let me know).
2. Create `tasks` as an empty array for users without one, this will not "skip" the users with an empty `tasks` array so performance will be affected but the aggregation will not fail, to do so add this `$project` stage before the `$lookup` stage:

```
{
    $project:{
        tasks: {$ifNull: ["$tasks", []]}
    }
}
```